# What's the meaning of Sūrya Maṇḍala Stōtram?

Tags: puranas, surya, stotra, bhavishya-purana

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32TGOFRIVmE

It appears to be from Bhaviṣya Purāṇa because it [ends with](http://stotrasamhita.net/wiki/Surya_Mandala_Stotram):

> ...
>
> sūryamaṇḍalasustrōtraṃ yaḥ paṭhēt satataṃ naraḥ | 
>   sarvapāpaviśuddhātmā sūryalōkē mahīyatē ||13||
>
> || iti śrī **bhaviṣyōttarapurāṇē** śrīkṛṣṇārjunasaṃvādē sūryamaṇḍalastōtraṃ sampūrṇam ||

Comment: You want a translation of the whole Stotra or only the meaning of the ending verse? or anything else..

Comment: In its entirety.

Comment: OK.. But it says Bhavishottara Purane..and that's not the same as the Bhavisya Purana.. It's an Upapurana if i am not wrong.

Comment: @Sar You sure about the edit? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhavishya_Purana#Uttaraparvan

Comment: Yeah. "The last book is sometimes treated as an independent purāṇa entitled Bhaviṣyottara-purāṇa. Minus this book, the number of verses comes to 14,000 or 14,500, a number generally and widely accepted by the scholars based on the information given in other purāṇas like the Matsya and the Agni". http://eoh.rkmathbangalore.org/describe/word/Bhavi%E1%B9%A3ya-pur%C4%81%E1%B9%87a. This is what I found. Besides. it is just asking about meaning and not about the Purana.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Nevertheless the question is related to a stotra from a specific purana. The tag is relevant.

Comment: Yoou ar efree to re-edit. But it is a mmeta tag.

Comment: http://www.celextel.org/stotras/grahas/suryamandalashtakam.html It has translation. I'm not posting it as answer due to copyright restrictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transliterated Stotra is found on [this page](http://stotrasamhita.net/wiki/Surya_Mandala_Stotram).

And, translations into English of all the verses saving the very first one are found [here](http://www.celextel.org/stotras/grahas/suryamandalashtakam.html).

But this second site is right-click protected. So can't copy from it. And i have not used that translation either.

> yanmaṇḍalaṃ dīptikaraṃ viśālaṃ ratnaprabhaṃ
>   tīvramanādirūpam|
>  dāridryaduḥkhakṣayakāraṇaṃ ca punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||1||
>
> Whose Mandala is the giver of illumination, is huge, is shining like
>   precious jewels, is brilliant and is of the begining-less form. Who
>   destroys poverty and grief, may that (or such) worship-worthy Savita (or sun)
>   purify us.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ dēvagaṇaiḥ supūjitaṃ vipraiḥ stutaṃ
>   bhāvanamuktikōvidam|
>  taṃ dēvadēvaṃ praṇamāmi sūryaṃ punātu
>   māṃ tatsaviturvarēṇyam||2||
>
> Whose Mandala is worshiped by the Devas, is praised by the Brahmins
>   (Vipra) and is the giver of liberation to humans, i salute that
>   worship-worthy sun. may that worship-worthy Savita (or sun)  purify
>   us.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ jñānaghanaṃ tvagamyaṃ trailōkyapūjyaṃ
>   triguṇātmarūpam|
>  samasta-tējōmaya-divyarūpaṃ punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||3||
>
> Whose Mandala knows the depth of knowledge (GyAnaghanamtvam), who is
>   worshiped by the three worlds, and is of the form of the Trigunatmika Nature
>   (Prakriti), is brilliant and who is of the divine form, may that
>   worship-worthy Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ gūḍhamatiprabōdhaṃ dharmasya vṛddhiṃ kurutē
>   janānām|
>  yatsarvapāpakṣayakāraṇaṃ ca punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||4||
>
> Whose Mandala blesses people with secret knowledge, who increases
>   Dharma (righteousness) in the masses, who is the reason of destruction
>   of all sins, may that worship-worthy Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ vyādhivināśadakṣaṃ yadṛgyajuḥsāmasu
>   sampragītam|
>  prakāśitaṃ yēna ca bhūrbhuvaḥ svaḥ punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||5||
>
> Whose Mandala is adept in destroying diseases, who has been described
>   in the Rig, Yajus and Sama Vedas, Whose illumination reaches the
>   earth, the mid-world and the heavens, may that worship-worthy Savita
>   purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ vēdavidō vadanti gāyanti
>   yaccāraṇa-siddhasaṅghāḥ|
>  yadyōginō yōgajuṣāṃ ca saṅghāḥ
>   punātu māṃ tatsaviturvarēṇyam||6||
>
> Whose Mandala is described by the Veda-knowers, and is being sung and
>   praised by the Siddhas and the Charanas, whom the Yogis meditate upon,
>   may that worship-worthy Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ sarvajanaiśca pūjitaṃ jyōtiśca kuryādiha
>   martyalōkē|
>  yatkālakālādyamanādirūpaṃ punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||7||
>
> Whose Mandala is worshiped by all the people, who illuminates the
>   earth, who is like the death (Kala) to death himself. And who is
>   without beginning, may that worship-worthy Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ viṣṇucāturmukhākhyaṃ yadakṣaraṃ pāpaharaṃ
>   janānām|
>  yatkālakalpakṣayakāraṇaṃ ca punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||8||
>
> Whose Mandala is of the form of Vishnu and Brahma (Chaturmukha), which
>   is indestructible, who is the remover of the sins of the masses. Who
>   is capable of even destroying the death, may that worship-worthy
>   Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ viśvasṛjaṃ
>   prasiddhamutpatti-rakṣā-pralaya-pragalbham|
>   yasmiñjagatsaṃharatē'khilaṃ ca punātu māṃ tatsaviturvarēṇyam||9||
>
> From whose Mandala this whole world has been created, who is capable
>   of performing the acts of creation, maintenance and destruction. In
>   which this whole universe dissolves into, may that worship-worthy
>   Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ sarvagatasya viṣṇōrātmā paraṃ dhāma
>   viśuddhatattvam|
>  sūkṣmāntarairyōgapathānugamyaṃ punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||10||
>
> Whose Mandala is of Vishnu's form, who is the ultimate destination for
>   the soul, who is the most pure principle (Vishuddha Tattva). One who
>   knows even the minutest variants of the path of Yoga, may that
>   worship-worthy Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ vēdavidō vadanti gāyanti
>   yaccāraṇa-siddhasaṅghāḥ|
>  yanmaṇḍalaṃ vēdavidaḥ smaranti
>   punātu māṃ tatsaviturvarēṇyam||11||
>
> Whose Mandala is being described by the knowers of the Brahman, the
>   Siddhas and Charanas sing praises of whom, whose greatness is being
>   remembered by the the knowers of the Vedas, may that worship-worthy
>   Savita purify me.
>
> yanmaṇḍalaṃ vēdavidōpagītaṃ yadyōgināṃ yōgapathānugamyam|
>   tatsarvavēdyaṃ praṇamāmi sūryaṃ punātu māṃ
>   tatsaviturvarēṇyam||12||
>
> Whose Mandala is being described by the knowers of Vedas, whom follow
>   the the adepts in Yoga, salutation to that Sun, may that
>   worship-worthy Savita purify me.
>
> sūryamaṇḍalasustrōtraṃ yaḥ paṭhēt satataṃ naraḥ|
>   sarvapāpaviśuddhātmā sūryalōkē mahīyatē||13||
>
> The man who always recites this good hymn (Sustotram), gets purified, destroys all his
>   sins thereby and enjoys in the realm of the Sun. (this is my own
>   translation, you can suggest corrections)

Finally,

> ||iti śrī bhaviṣyōttarapurāṇē śrīkṛṣṇārjunasaṃvādē
>   sūryamaṇḍalastōtraṃ sampūrṇam|
>
> Here ends the Suryamandalastotram which is found in the Bhavishyottara
>   Purana and which is of the form of a dialogue between Sri Krishna and
>   Arjuna.

The expression "Punatu mam", which is repeated in all the verses, is a request- "purify me". And, the "Yanmandalam",  which all the verses start with, is "Whose Mandala" with "Mandala" meaning "the station or Orb" of the Sun. Others can suggest a better translation for this word though.

I have used [this PDF](http://www.spiritualbee.com/media/surya-ashtakam-sanskrit-verses-hindi-translation.pdf) for the translation. It is Sanskrit Slokas with Hindi translation. I am not that expert in Hindi but somehow managed to tally the translations with the Sanskrit verses in giving the English translation.

IMO, the translation of the copy-protected site is wrong at many points. And, the only translation which i kept from it is for this "yanmaṇḍalaṃ gūḍhamatiprabōdhaṃ".